# Add reminders for future date time using html/javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, html5-canvas

I have an web application where I set reminder for future date and time, when the time comes it should notify the user.
I have few issues doing so
I have stored the date time in oracle database and I want my application to keep looking at it and trigger notification whenever it meets the time.
Is storing the date time in database is correct approach? or is there any other approach where we can easily trigger? I am not completely okay with session/local storage.
Somebody please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to keep you notifications in a oracle database assuming you other user data is stored along with it. And you have a decent auth method.

Using localStorage can be is okay in some situations, but can be a bit of a challenge: (users use other browsers, has activated some sort of internet security that automatically removes localStorage)

Cookies is another variable client side solution, but it too suffers from some of the same issues as localStorage.

sessionStorage is not the way to go: sessionStorage is only kept alive as long as the tab is open

Keeping notifications serverside, has the added benefit, that you can send other kind of notifications (sms, push or mail)

pull the notifications from oracle could look somting like this:
`select * from notifications where user_id = :user_id and notify_date between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate+1)`

If you want to handle dates in JS, and store them in local storage: consider using ISO 8601 date string, javascript dates quickly becomes a pain to work with. (time zone/daylight saving...ect.)

here is a quick example
https://codepen.io/morophix/pen/zYzKMjm

Comment: But how do you pull will be the real challenge right? from javascript when exactly you will call database to fetch the notification date time.
Consider I used localStorage and wanted to trigger notification/reminded on 10th september, now I created this object and stored in localstorage but how exactly its going to use the added entry in local storage and trigger on 10th september

Comment: You cannot interact with oracle from client script, you need some server logic to help

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment, please refer the earlier comment

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a pure js solution

Comment: You could also consider using a framework like FireBase - https://firebase.google.com